# Centering map to visible area

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, mkmapview, mapkit

In my app I am adding an MKMapView as a view ontop of an UITableView. The MapView is of height 250 with a visible area of 80. 
Whenever a location is found, I would like to center that location (annotation) in the visible area, the bottom 80px of the MapView.

this is what I have so far: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3077127/MapViewDemo.mov

I have tried a bunch of different things but I can't find a solution. I removed the things I have tested for now.
This is my code:

```
float kMapHeaderHeight = 250.0f;
float kMapContentInset = 80.0f;
BOOL favFirstPositionFound = NO;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Favorites", @"FavoritesViewController")];

    // Set up the edit and add buttons.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -kMapHeaderHeight, self.tableView.frame.size.width, kMapHeaderHeight)];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
    [self.mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [self.tableView addSubview:self.mapView];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kMapContentInset, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView.isDragging) {
        if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y < kMapContentInset-((self.view.bounds.size.height/3)*2))
        {
            NSLog(@"Far enough!");
        }
    }
}
[...]
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    location=newLocation.coordinate;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center=location;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    if (!favFirstPositionFound)
    {
        span.latitudeDelta=.010;
        span.longitudeDelta=.010;
    }
    else {
        span.latitudeDelta = self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta;
        span.longitudeDelta = self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    }

    region.span=span;

    favFirstPositionFound = YES;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it took a while... but I figured it out myself.

What I do now is that I use the current location which is an `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and get the corresponding map points from it. Then I adapt the positioning using the width and height of the visible rect of the map.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3077127/MapViewDemoResult.mov

The code is not yet refactored, since I just found the solution... but feel free to do that yourself ;)

The end-result:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    float offset = fabs(self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
    float diff = (1.0 - ((offset/2) / kMapHeaderHeight));

    MKMapRect r = [self.mapView visibleMapRect];
    MKMapPoint pt = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location);

    r.origin.x = pt.x - r.size.width * 0.50;
    r.origin.y = pt.y - r.size.height * diff;
    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:r animated:NO];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=.010;
    span.longitudeDelta=.010;

    region.span=span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

    if (scrollView.isDragging) {
        if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y < kMapContentInset-((self.view.bounds.size.height/3)*2))
        {
            NSLog(@"Halfway there!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Found a bug which I need to fix, which is that if you pull the table upwards, the section head will keep its place but the content will scroll upwards behind it into the mapview.